# change android toolbar popup menu theme from dark to light

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-toolbar

I am using the appcompat v22 toolbar widget

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I want a light themed popup menu ( white background with black  text ) Problem is the popup menu is always turning out be dark themed (looks like it is picking the styles from ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar and setting  android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat. Light" is not making any difference.

The problem occurred when I moved from app:theme to android:theme ( that's what is recommended if we need to use appcompat v22 version

I tried overriding the style and setting many values within the style

```
<style name="ToolBarPopUpTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

But in vain, any idea how to get a light themed Popup menu in the ActionBar ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to go back to app:popupTheme.

If you look at the source code for `Toolbar.java` you'll see the following on line 263.

```
setPopupTheme(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Toolbar_popupTheme, 0));
```

R in this case is `android.support.v7.appcompat.R` (check out line 32), so the `Toolbar` is using the `app:` namespace for its attributes and not the `android:` namespace.

Out of curiosity, where did you read that you should be using the `android:theme` attribute?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about the code, i got it working by manually calling the setPopupTheme with the ToolBarPopUpTheme in my Activity. Things started to work. Regarding the moving to android:theme, I noticed one crash when i was playing around with the app with the logcat msg "08-17 20:00:51.290  32511-32511/? I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead."

Answer (score 1):

As far as i see you are using the wrong parent style.

Give this a try:

```
<style name="ToolBarPopUpTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.